# what are those tiny images in google map and is it possible to add your own?

Tags: android, svg, google-maps-android-api-2

I was working on the small project using google map and I am not able to get the details of the images, meaning what type of images are those (SVG, png or jpg), and is it possible to add your own custom image.if yes how to do it, please follow the attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Those small icons are google registered places, It can be of various categories, You can't add your image ,it will be based on categories.

follow these step to add a google place.

Before you add a place, check if it exists on the map. If not, follow the steps below:

> Open Map Maker.
>
> ```
> In the top left, click Add New.
>
> Select Add a Place.
>
> Select the Satellite view and zoom in to the appropriate location.
>
> Drop the marker on top of the building where your place exists.
>
> From the drop-down menu, select a category. 
>
> You can also search for a category.
>
> Enter the name of the place. 
>
> To add multiple names, click Add more names. 
>
> To add more details, click Continue. To discard your edit, click Cancel.
>
> Click Save.
> ```

Sources:https://support.google.com/mapmaker/answer/1096044?hl=en

Use Google Place API for adding google place though your app..

Source : https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place